# Struts 2 Validation message with HTML code inside

Tags: validation, struts2

I'm trying to create a Struts2 Validation Message with some HTML code inside.

For example:

```xml
<field-validator type="regex">
    <param name="expression">
        <![CDATA[^([0-9]+|[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$]]>
    </param>
    <message>
      <b>${Price}</b> field for <b>${fundDescription}</b> and 
         <b>${currencyDescription}</b> must be a number and in the correct format
    </message>
</field-validator>
```

I know that `<b>${Price}</b>` and `&lt;b&gt;${Price}&lt;/b&gt;` don't work. Is there any way to do that?

I'm not including my entire code because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is escaped (doesn't show html) for security reasons. If you are using `xhtml` theme (which is default) the escaping happens in FreeMarker template.

You can create your own template and display error as it is or you can use different theme (e.g. `simple`) and show errors using `<s:fielderror>` tag with `escape` attribute set to `false`.

BUT be aware that not escaping html content you don't totally control can lead to security issues.

Comment: Thanks. It worked as I needed.. Now I have to decide to use or not because the security issues.